# What information belongs in per-tag FAQs?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

Since these per-tag FAQs are new, it is quite uncertain of what we should actually put in them. Please list any ideas of what kind of content belongs in them and how to decide what to put in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest (and *have* suggested, for the [C# tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=c%23&sort=info&pagesize=50) :)

- A brief description for people who have no idea what the tag is
- Some very common questions (either as links to good instances on SO, or possibly questions with answers)
- Resources for further study (e.g. for C#: MSDN, books and blogs)

Comment: +1 The C# tag is very good. I have some minor questions about it. (1) Are the description and Hello World too long? They push the FAQ and resources down, so people need to scroll to see them. (2) Add some resources for beginners? The C# spec and Eric Lippert's blog are great, but perhaps add links to (for example) the C# express edition download and the Microsoft C# developer centre site, which has some content for beginners?

Comment: @MarkJ: Yes, I think both of those points are reasonable. I'm reluctant to arbitrarily remove the content in the description, but I may move it below the fold, as it were. I was anticipating a single paragraph. Must add a FAQ about floating point, too...

Comment: I think all of Tony the Pony's misconceptions would be great additions to the FAQ! Probably on every tag wiki...